# action script trace does not work in FDT

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to built my first project on as3, using FDT, but trace does not work, it just does not output anything in console. The code does not contain any errors or warnings and works just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed Flash Debug player?

Comment: @putvande, before posting I had google and read about that, but downloading this `Download the Windows Flash Player 11.9 Projector content debugger` from here http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html, when I click on exe file it just opens a window of like flash player, that u can open swf files, but it does not install anything. Or I chose a wrong file to download ? I use win 7 THanks

Comment: This may occur if you have more than 1 instance of flash-player application on the same computer. Make sure that default program to open *.swf files is Flash Player 11.9 Projector content debugger (probably swfs are opened not by debugger).

Comment: Also check out flashlog.txt file, to see if any of your traces appeared there (“C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs”).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are compiling your project in "release" mode, in this mode no traces work, and other debug functions don't work as well. The default configuraion of FlashDevelop has the switch located in the main button bar right under the menu, and the switch is a dropdown list having two positions, `Debug` and `Release`. Set this to `Debug` and try again.